# Find external IP address and log address number in powershell?

Tags: powershell, logging, ip, external, ip-address

I have made a powershell script to find my external IP address. Here is the code I have so far:

```
$wc=New-Object net.webclient
$wc.downloadstring("http://checkip.dyndns.com") -replace "[^\d\.]" >External_IP.txt
```

Im going to have this script run every week and wish to keep a log of the IP address changes. For now it saves the external IP address in a text file called External_IP.txt. When run multiple times it doesn't add a new line to the text file.

Could someone give me info on this please? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe to the `Out-File` cmdlet and specify the Append switch

```
... -replace "[^\d\.]" | Out-File External_IP.txt -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `>` to write to a file, try using `>>` which should append to the file if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Shays answer is correct in PowerShell V3
I am not sure if you have he -append option in v2

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = "http://ammaso.com/IP"
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webpage = $client.downloadString($source)
$obj = New-Object Object
$obj | Add-Member Noteproperty externalIP -value $webpage
$obj
```

Comment: Explain your answer and why the code works by [edit]ing the answer.